# Как вернуть ветвь из дерева?

Tags: java, дерево

Есть TreeMultiMap, где ключ - сет навыков, а значение - лист вакансий с этими навыками. И если мне требуются навыки А и Б, то я должен получить лист с вакансиями, в список навыков которых входят А и Б. Значит, если всего существует три навыка : А, Б и С, то я должен получить лист вакансий с навыками А и Б, а так же с навыками А, Б и С. То есть всю ветвь дерева, начинающуюся с А и Б. Есть ли готовое решение для таких случаев? И если нет, как лучше реализовать данное поведение?

Comment: а как насчет multimap (ключ - множество значений)? не подходит? примеры реализации здесь https://www.baeldung.com/guava-multimap

Comment: @Дмитрий , как именно можно получить листы для АБ и АБС как в тексте вопроса с помощью данной коллекции?

Comment: у вас в вопросе ключ - сет. это не очень гибкое решение, потому как ваш хеш считается из определенного количества навыков, лежащих в сете. ключ должен совпадать, чтобы искать по хешу, посему ничего найти вы там не сможете, если списко навыков изменится. но если создать мультимэп с ключом - единичным навыком , значением - сетом вакансий (их идентификаторов), то имея список навыков , можно последовательно найти все вакансии для каждого навыка. а, поскольку вы получаете значение в виде сета, то достаточно несложно проверить вхождения полученных списков.